tensorflow 2.4.0 requires typing-extensions~=3.7.4 && anyio 4.3.0 requires typing-extensions>=4.1
I want to use GPU with tensorflow
My issue
tensorflow 2.4.0 requires typing-extensions~=3.7.4 
anyio 4.3.0 requires typing-extensions>=4.1

So, Now what version of typing-extensions to install because one install and break another and vice-versa. How to solve it?
I have 
Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic
Cuda version 11.0
GCC = 7.3.1
pip3 = 23.3.1
Python = 3.8.0

My requirments
tensorflow=2.4.0
nibabel=3.8
cv2=3.8
imageio=3.8
ipywidgets=3.8
tqdm=308
PIL=3.8
fastai=3.8

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.4.0 requires typing-extensions~=3.7.4, but you have typing-extensions 4.1.0 which is incompatible.

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
anyio 4.3.0 requires typing-extensions>=4.1; python_version < "3.11", but you have typing-extensions 3.7.4.3 which is incompatible.
async-lru 2.0.4 requires typing-extensions>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.11", but you have typing-extensions 3.7.4.3 which is incompatible.

I tried typing-extensions diffrent versions but not worked
